# Right way to make AJAX GET and POST calls in EmberJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ember.js, ember-model

I've started working on EmberJS and I absolutely love it. It does have a learning curve but I believe it has fundamentally very meaningful principles.

My questions is how to make GET and POST calls in Ember JS. I understand that there are models / store, but models (in my opinion) would be to only a particular entity's attributes.

Any thoughts on the following questions would be great.

```
1. USER A send friend request to USER B. Should there be a "Request"
   model? And do I just make a POST request?

2. Some arbitrary data needs to be returned for the page. Not
   particularly of a model. Should I still make a model for that?
   For use a simple GET request?

3. User needs to update this profile photo. How can the file
   to be uploaded, be set as a model attribute?
```

How should I go about making regular GET and POST calls (if I am to do them at all). Just use jQuery's $.ajax() or is there another way. I also found a service [ember-ajax](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-ajax) which has extended the $.ajax into a promises style.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Long live EmberJS :)

Answer (score 4):

First option: You can use `ember-data`. It has customizations such as [serializers](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/models/customizing-serializers/) or [adapters](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/models/customizing-adapters/).

Second option: You can use addons like `ember-ajax`.

Our usage is just using jQuery's `ajax()`. We wrote a service that just wraps `jquery.ajax()` and use it everywhere in our code. We believe that it gives us a flexibility of writing different kind of queries. We don't have any `model` of `ember-data`.

Sample -*pseudo*- code:

```
  export default Ember.Service.extend({
    doPostCall(target, data, options=null){
       //consider cloning options with Ember.$.extend
       var requestOptions= options || {};
       requestOptions.url=target;
       requestOptions.type='POST';
       requestOptions.data=JSON.stringify(data);
       doRemoteCall(requestOptions);
    },

    doGetCall(target, data=null, options=null){
       //consider cloning options with Ember.$.extend
       var requestOptions=options || {};
       requestOptions.url=target;
       requestOptions.type='GET';
       requestOptions.data=data;
       doRemoteCall(requestOptions);
    },

    doRemoteCall(requestOptions){
      //assign default values in here:
      //  such as contentType, dataType, withCredentials...

      Ember.$.ajax(requestOptions)
        .then(function(data) {
            Ember.run(null, resolve, data);
         }, function(jqXHR , textStatus, errorThrown) {
            jqXHR.then = null;
            Ember.run(null, reject, jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
         });
    }
  });
```

PS: By the way, if you need to run your app in server-side (with fastboot), you cannot use jQuery. So use `ember-network`.

Comment: I like it.  Do you ever find yourself missing the serializers and adapters with this approach?

Comment: No, never. Because I don't have any model. Very rarely, I miss model, but any `Ember.Object` is enough for us.

Answer (score 3):

If you are performing CRUD operations over models, ember-data is nice. In most apps, CRUD operations account for ~90% of requests.

There is occasions where an app needs to make requests that not ideal for ember-data, and that is where `ember-ajax` enters the game. It allows you to do requests like you'd do with just jQuery, with the nice addition that requests are done though a service that has some extension points to allow to customize things like headers that are used app-wide, which is more complex with just raw jquery.

If your app is going to run in fastboot, you should use `ember-network`, because it works both in the browser and in node, while jquery/ember-ajax does don't.

Answer (score 1):

Current best practise would be ember-fetch. since [ember-network](https://github.com/tomdale/ember-network) is deprecated in favor of [ember-fetch](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-fetch).

You can just install ember-fetch addon by running the below command,

```
ember install ember-fetch
```

and then just import fetch and you are good to use fetch method.

```
import fetch from 'fetch';
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return fetch('/my-cool-end-point.json').then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    });
  }
});
```